# How can i separate php code with html to have them both clean and separate in different files?

Tags: php, html, authentication, logout

what i want to do is something like this

```
<div id="login">
            <h6> Log in </h6>
            <form method="POST">
                <p> Usuario: <input type="text" name="user"/></p>
                <p> Password: <input type="text" name="pass"/></p>
                <input name="accion" value="login" type="hidden"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

and i want to separate with a php code that makes me log in if you have cirtain user, what i did was :

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST["accion"] == "login"){
    if($_POST["user"]=="root" && $_POST["pass"]=="123"){
        $_SESSION["usuario"]= $_POST["user"];
        $_SESSION["time"]=time() - $_SESSION;   
        echo $_SESSION["usuario"];
    }else{  
        $error= "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto";
        echo $error;
    }
}
$logeado = isset($_SESSION["usuario"]);
?>
```

so, how do i link this functions so that when the client hits the submit it executes this function? After that i would like to know how to change my view there if he succeeds to his username and to tell him he is logged like a message, if you can help me i'd appreciate it! thank you

Comment: Look into MVC (Model/View/Controller) architecture. Depending on the size of your project, I would consider using a framework like Laravel which already uses MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the form action to your form.

```
    <div id="login">
        <h6> Log in </h6>
        <form method="POST" action="path-to-your-file.php">
            <p> Usuario: <input type="text" name="user"/></p>
            <p> Password: <input type="text" name="pass"/></p>
            <input name="accion" value="login" type="hidden"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Add `header('Location: redirect-location.php');` to your login success function to redirect the user.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST["accion"] == "login"){
    if($_POST["user"]=="root" && $_POST["pass"]=="123"){
        $_SESSION["usuario"]= $_POST["user"];
        $_SESSION["time"]=time() - $_SESSION;   
        echo $_SESSION["usuario"];
        header('Location: redirect-location.php');
    }else{  
        $error= "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto";
        echo $error;
    }
}
$logeado = isset($_SESSION["usuario"]);
?>
```

Comment: okay awesome, one more thing, how do i add more code php to that login.php to for example log out, or do i have to create a new file every time i want to execute a different php code? @nunmsu

Comment: You can make one file with functions, and you call those functions with the form action. Or you can make several PHP files, up to you :)

Comment: oh btw one more thing, how do i call the function? @ numsu

Comment: You can make a function with `function logout() { return true; }`. You can call that function like `logout();`. If you call it like `$logout = logout();`. The function will return the value `true` to the parameter `$logout`. So you can check if the function went through. Now you need to study yourself for a while ;) Thanks for writing my nick with the right syntax this time! :) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called MVC pattern, or Model View Controller pattern. It separates responsibilities of the different components of a web application.

The only best practice to answer your question is to use a PHP framework. Any framework. Personally I would recommend you to use Laravel, but there are plenty of them: Zend, CakePHP, Symfony, Yii.